# How can I play back audio at a slower rate?

Tags: audio, media-player, vlc

I'm doing speech to text to an audio file.

While on PC what I do is slow down the audio in VLC. But at the time I have no access to one.

How can I do this on Android?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Answer (score 3):

[VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) allows you to alter the playback speed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yeah! It was fine before I played the media. I found that unlike the desktop version, it broadens the pitch.